# "Cross-tree" inter-container communication between encapsulated objects

Tags: oop, encapsulation, organization

Encapsulation lends itself to hierarchical "silos" or "trees" of objects, with a given application's major functionalities decomposed into core trunks, each further decomposed into sub-functionalities instantiated as sub-branch member objects of their respective branches.

As an example, suppose I'm programming a GUI in QT. To separate GUI elements from business logic, for every widget I have a class for the GUI elements, a class for the business logic associated with the GUI elements, and what I'll call a controller which serves as a container for both and exists primarily to pass signals/slots in between. I understand this pattern to be called dependency injection.

Let's suppose our application has 2 windows A and B.

Window A contains 2 independent widgets that have separate business functions i and ii, so we might have the structure `A::i` and `A::ii`, where :: is "contains an instance of" and not "extends".

Then i and ii both contain gui and business logic units, so we have `A::i::business` and `A::i::gui`.

Now, suppose `A::i::business` and `A::ii::business` want to pass information between each other, or engage in bidirectional communication with the model-view for my database, identified as MV. Generally speaking, what are my options for doing this?

What I've thought of so far:

1) Pass signals up and down the tree, i.e., the Verilog solution. This seems the most strictly object oriented, but most tedious.

2) Have a flatter architecture to ease the implementation of solution 1). This hurts encapsulation.

3) Make `A::i::business` and `A::ii::business` public all the way down, and have either the other object or a third-party shared class access `A::i::business` or `A::ii:business` directly. This hurts encapsulation.

4) Have a relatively unencapsulated object, like the database MV or some other form of "shared storage", exist in a public form near the top level of the program with few/ no super-containers. This seems most appealing, as the relatively encapsulated objects can stay encapsulated and communicate through unidirectional reading/ writing to something that's unencapsulated. However, if I want other objects to perform actions based on changes shared storage, some way of notifying the dependent objects while keeping them private is necessary.  This might be called the "multi-threading inspired" or "multi-processing inspired" model of communication.

And any other suggestions you all may have.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506441/keeping-the-gui-separate) post here, but at my level of understanding, the solutions in the accepted answer such as controller, listener and pub-sub, refer to general design patterns that don't seem to commit to a solution for the concrete problem of how to route signals and make decisions about public/ private accessibility of member classes. It may be the case that these solutions have associated conventions for where the communication objects go and how they access the different variables in either silo that I'm not familiar with.

Most generally speaking, I seem to be running into a general problem of communication across container-trees in well-encapsulated programming.

For future reference, is there a general term for this problem to aide future searching? Is my architectural approach of having the object-container structure directly reflecting the tree-decomposition of application functionality lending itself to too hierarchical a design, and would a different pattern of object containment and cross-branch communication be more optimal?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54577124/3096593